# How do I fix a Python3 KeyError: '&quot;id_str&quot;'?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, twitter, runtime-error

I'm working on scraping Tweets, using the following script. While running it, I get the following two errors, but the one I am mostly concerned about is the KeyError:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Exporter.py", line 76, in
>   main
>       got3.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria, receiveBuffer)   File
>   "/Users/MacbookPro/PycharmProjects/cs446/trend_map-master/getoldtweets/got3/manager/TweetManager.py",
>   line 40, in getTweets
>       json_to_use = ((json['items_html']).format('div.js-stream-tweet')) KeyError: '"id_str"'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Exporter.py", line 85, in
>   
>       main(sys.argv[1:])   File "Exporter.py", line 78, in main
>       except arg: TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed`

The code is below:

```
@staticmethod
def getTweets(tweetCriteria, receiveBuffer=None, bufferLength=100):
    refreshCursor = ''

    results = []
    resultsAux = []
    cookieJar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()

    active = True

    while active:
        json = TweetManager.getJsonReponse(tweetCriteria, refreshCursor, cookieJar)
        if len(json['items_html'].strip()) == 0:
            break

        refreshCursor = json['min_position']
        # print(json['items_html']('div.js-stream-tweet'))
        json_to_use = ((json['items_html']).format('div.js-stream-tweet'))
        tweets = PyQuery(json_to_use)
        # print(tweets)

        # print(len(tweets))

        if len(tweets) == 0:
            break

        for tweetHTML in tweets:
            tweetPQ = PyQuery(tweetHTML)
            tweet = models.Tweet()

            usernameTweet = tweetPQ("span.username.js-action-profile-name b").text()
            txt = re.sub(
                r"\s+", " ", tweetPQ("p.js-tweet-text").text().replace('# ', '#').replace('@ ', '@'))
            retweets = int(tweetPQ("span.ProfileTweet-action--retweet span.ProfileTweet-actionCount").attr(
                "data-tweet-stat-count").replace(",", ""))
            favorites = int(tweetPQ("span.ProfileTweet-action--favorite span.ProfileTweet-actionCount").attr(
                "data-tweet-stat-count").replace(",", ""))
            dateSec = int(tweetPQ("small.time span.js-short-timestamp").attr("data-time"))
            id = tweetPQ.attr("data-tweet-id")
            permalink = tweetPQ.attr("data-permalink-path")
            user_id = int(tweetPQ("a.js-user-profile-link").attr("data-user-id"))

            geo = TweetManager.findLocation(usernameTweet)
            urls = []
            for link in tweetPQ("a"):
                try:
                    urls.append((link.attrib["data-expanded-url"]))
                except KeyError:
                    pass
            tweet.id = id
            tweet.permalink = 'https://twitter.com' + permalink
            tweet.username = usernameTweet

            tweet.text = txt
            tweet.date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dateSec)
            tweet.formatted_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                dateSec).strftime("%a %b %d %X +0000 %Y")
            tweet.retweets = retweets
            tweet.favorites = favorites
            tweet.mentions = " ".join(re.compile('(@\\w*)').findall(tweet.text))
            tweet.hashtags = " ".join(re.compile('(#\\w*)').findall(tweet.text))
            tweet.geo = geo
            tweet.urls = ",".join(urls)
            tweet.author_id = user_id
            tweet.tweetPQ = tweetPQ
            tweet.rawhtml = tweetHTML
            tweet.tweets = tweets
            tweet.alljson = json

            results.append(tweet)
            resultsAux.append(tweet)

            if receiveBuffer and len(resultsAux) >= bufferLength:
                receiveBuffer(resultsAux)
                resultsAux = []

            if tweetCriteria.maxTweets > 0 and len(results) >= tweetCriteria.maxTweets:
                active = False
                break

    if receiveBuffer and len(resultsAux) > 0:
        receiveBuffer(resultsAux)

    return results
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. I tried looking it up and I don't see an issue primarily with my formatting of how I make the requests. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: where is your `main(sys.argv[1:])`?

Comment: It is the following, in fact if you go to /getoldtweets, you can see the source code in its entirety: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SamOh/trend_map/master/getoldtweets/Exporter.py

Comment: what is `arg` in `except arg`?

Comment: error message is obvious: you can't `except` anything but `BaseException` subclasses

Comment: what should I `except` then?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: complete question with code from link